Obtaining z-scores for coefficients of quantile regression with sampling weights applied in R
I would need to obtain z-scores for coefficients of quantile regression with sampling weights applied in R to be able to compare results from different datasets.
Can I just compute them as "z-score = coefficent/SE" or is there another specific formula for quantile regression?
